# Best practice to fill dropdowns in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, drop-down-menu

So, I have this grid where the user can edit the information in a edit form that appears once the user press the edit button of the desired row

On this form, I have several dropdowns that needs to be filled with the options the user can select to edit the row object information.

My issue here is, before I edit the object, I need to lock it in the database, so no other user can modify it or query it while it's being edited, so before showing the edit form, I see if the object is not locked, and if available, lock it.

For this, I call a api service, lock it, and receive the result, then, copy the object to edit, set the edit form show variable to true and show the form

What I'm trying to figure out is, whats the best practice to retrieve the dropdowns data?

I already have this

```
callApi.get("/api/object/checklock/" + objectid, function(result) {
    if (result === true) {
        $scope.$apply(() => {
            $scope.objectToModify = angular.copy(object); // clone object. Never modify over the original
            $scope.showObjectEditForm = true; // show object edit form
            $scope.showResults = false; // hide results table
        });
    } else if (result !== '') {
        // object locked by another user
    }
}, $scope.fnShowErrorMsg);
```

Where should I call the other rest services to retrieve the dropdown values?

I'm aware that an apply inside another apply it's not permited, and the dropdown values depend on some of the information contained in the object to edit, so I can't have the dropdown filled from the start, need to be retrieved with info from the selected row

thanks

Comment: what *"other api's"*? Issue is not clear

Comment: not apis perse, api services, as to retrieve the dropdowns data to be filled with

Comment: ok... think i get it ... you need to use object to make more server side calls?

Comment: Yeah, but I think i just figured out. On the same apply to show the results and copy the object to modify, I call the services to retrieve the dropdowns data to fill. Once the dropdown are filled, due to the ng-model binding, the modified object value is shown correctly. I just need now, to know when the last dropdown has been processed, so the form is not shown until every field has it's values